# Unable to connect to mySql running on my host from docker container

Tags: java, mysql, docker

I have deployed a docker container having a simple Java-JDBC Code build from openjdk7 base image.

Now I have `mysql` running on my local machine on port 3306. Now How can I connect to mysql running on host machine from docker container?

I have deployed container using:

```
docker run -it -p 25000:27000 -p 3307:3306 94e56cffbdf7 bash
```

But in the container, when I try to run the javaCode, I get an error like:

> com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException:
>   Communications link failure
>
> The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds
>   ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.

If I try to connect to mysql by using the command:

```
mysql -h 10.10.35.129 -p 3307 -u root -p
```

where 10.01.35.129 is my host machine's ip.

I get error:

> bash: mysql: command not found

For refrence I am also attaching the Java Code I am trying to run inside docker container:

```
package jdbcCodes;

import java.sql.*;

public class MySqlJDBC {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try{
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            // here testEmp is DB name and root is user and xxx os password
            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3307/testEmp","root","xxx");
            Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs=stmt.executeQuery("select * from tempEntry");
            while(rs.next()){
                System.out.println(rs.getInt(1)+" "+rs.getString(2));           
            }
            con.close();            
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Repaeating my question: 
How to conect to mysql running on host machine from docker contaimner?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [From inside of a Docker container, how do I connect to the localhost of the machine?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24319662/from-inside-of-a-docker-container-how-do-i-connect-to-the-localhost-of-the-mach)

Answer (score 1):

Inside a docker container, *localhost* refers to the container itself, unless you use `--network host`, which has other consequences. Rather, you want to refer to the host by using its IP address, `10.10.35.129`.

The reason why the `mysql` command is not working in the container is because you don't haven't it installed. By default in docker, networking, processes, filesystems and users (amongst others) are all seperated inside the container.

Comment: I even tried running container by adding flag `--network host` . Still same issue. :(

Comment: With that flag, try using 127.0.0.1